# npm run doesn't work after install git for windows

Tags: node.js, git, electron

I installed [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win). Since then I can't run any electron project. Before the git installation it worked perfectly.

Now I have this error in the terminal on Visual Studio Code. How do I fix this?

```
Lifecycle scripts included in sample_gym_app:
  start
    electron .
PS E:\projects\electron test\gymapp> npm run
Scripts available in sample_gym_app via `npm run-script`:
  pack
    build --dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have left out one of your `npm` parameters.

Try `npm run start`

The `npm run` command expects to receive the name of a script to run, oftentimes `start`.

If this answer is correct and works for you, consider doing some further reading on npm commands. See https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/ for example.